# How to read a war/jar file which does not have manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest, war

I have a war file which does not contains manifest not even `META-INF` folder. Now my problem is that I wrote a code which was working fine with normal war files containing manifests. Now I am required to read a war file which does not contain manifest.

When I check

```
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
```

This condition is just skipped. Is there any API which treats it just as a normal zip file or is there any workaround.

I have tried with `JarEntry` as well as `ZipEntry`. Here is a small snippet that should be explanatory.

```
try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(applicationPack);
            ZipArchiveInputStream zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(fis);
            ArchiveEntry ze = null;
            File applicationPackConfiguration;           
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            // do someting
}
```

What can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply list contents with [ZipFile](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/ListZip.html) class:

```
try {
  // Open the ZIP file
  ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("filename.zip");

  // Enumerate each entry
  for (Enumeration entries = zf.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {
    // Get the entry name
    String zipEntryName = ((ZipEntry)entries.nextElement()).getName();
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/ListZip.html). Another example for [retrieving the file from zip](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/GetZip.html).

**Update:**

Code above indeed has problems with zip files that contain only directory as a top-level element.

This code works (tested):

```
    try {
        // Open the ZIP file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/your.war"));
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

        ZipEntry entry = null;

        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
            // Get the entry name
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: I tested those examples but if we use entries.hasMoreElements() it just does not read any entries from there. This is where I am stuck

Comment: I tried the same code with one war containing manifest and other without it. Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: No the update is same in concept as the code I posted. zis.getNextEntry() looks for manifest first if it does not get it , it treats it as empty

Comment: war and jar files are just zip files, so this code should read them and display contents. Manifest has nothing to do with zip file format.

Comment: Not correct: `.getNextEntry()` looks for new entry (file or directory) in a zip file. War manifest is just a file within a zip.

Comment: I tested this code and it worked on a jar file (no manifest). Does it work on your war file?

Comment: I wish I could send you my war file to test it yourself

Comment: Can you open this file on your OS? Maybe rename it first to zip.

Comment: But what I am expecting is a war file.

Comment: Sigh.. war file is a compressed file that has same format as jar file which has the same format as zip file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes from [java.util.zip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package. Just replace ZipArchiveInputStream with ZipInputStream and ArchiveEntry with ZipEntry:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your.war"));
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
   System.out.println(ze.getName());
}
```

Comment: I was using ZipEntry at the first place then switched to ZipArchiveInputStream . None works

Comment: Is applicationPack a java.util.File?

Comment: What XML? You shoud use new File("your.war") here, if you want to open it. See [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)FileInputStream[/link]

Comment: errr sorry my mistake. The argument applicationPack is a war file which I am trying to read the contents of.

Comment: I would have got file not found exception

Comment: Have no idea. Both my and @Peter Knego examples works fine for me. Probably, you need to put bigger piece of code here.